# 'require': cannot load such file -- pry-byebug (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I'm doing some training at the moment (so newbie) and I'm trying to run the console.rb file in a Ruby/psql project. The project has customers, films and tickets.

The object if to do CRUD commands on the data once I can get the console.rb file to run.

I have empty db tables at the moment for the three .rb files.

```
RUBY VERSION:
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]

PSQL VERSION:
psql (PostgreSQL) 11.5
```

File structure for the project is as follows:

```
specs
 - film_spec.rb (empty)
 - ticket_spec.rb (empty)
 - customer_spec.rb (empty)

models
 - film.rb
 - ticket.rb
 - customer.rb

db
 - cinema_homework.sql
 - sql_runner.rb
 - customer_spec.rb (empty)

console.rb
```

The console file is:

```
require('pry')
require_relative('models/customers')
require_relative('models/films')
require_relative('models/tickets')

Tickets.delete_all()
Customers.delete_all()
Films.delete_all()

customer1 = Customers.new({'name' => 'Geddy', 'funds' => 100})
customers1.save()

customer2 etc

customers3 ett


film1 = Films.new({'title' => 'A Show of Hands', 'price' => 20})
film1.save()

film2 etc ...

film3 etc ...

ticket1 = Tickets.new({'customers_id' => customers1.id, 'films_id' => film1.id})
ticket1.save()

ticket2 etc ...

ticket3 etc ...

binding.pry

nil
```

I get this error but for the life of me cannot work out what is going on. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from console.rb:2:in `<main>'
    2: from console.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    1: from /Users/johnhannah/codeclan/week_3/day_5/cinema_homework/models/customers.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/johnhannah/codeclan/week_3/day_5/cinema_homework/models/customers.rb:1:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /Users/johnhannah/codeclan/week_3/day_5/cinema_homework/db/sql_runner (LoadError)
```

Customers.rb

```
require_relative('../db/sql_runner.rb')

class Customers

  attr_reader :id
  attr_accessor :name, :funds

  def initialize(options)
    @id = options['id'].to_i if options['id']
    @name = options['name']
    @funds = options['funds'].to_i
  end

  def save()
    sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, funds)
    VALUES ($1, $2)
    RETURNING id"
    values = [@name, @funds]
    customers = SqlRunner.run(sql, values).first
    @id = customers['id'].to_i
  end

end
```

Comment: The problem is on line number 1 of `customer.rb`, maybe post that file too.

Comment: I’ve changed the require relative but not clear on why it’s an issue.
Another eye over it would be good.

It’s been a long day …:)

Comment: If you think of it like this, then it will mostly make sense: `require` is used to load gems, and `require_relative` is used to load your own files. For more in-depth explanation, you will have to do some Googling, but with that basic understanding you will do OK in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to load all the files in the executable file (`console.rb`).

As you did it all the classes will be available in all the files when you run `console.rb`.

So in the top of `console.rb` write something like

```
require 'pry'
require_relative 'db/sql_runner'
require_relative 'models/film'
require_relative 'models/ticket'
require_relative 'models/customer'
```

(The sequence of these lines can be changed depending on the sequence of loading classes)

Also check word form of your classes. Usually class name is singular, not plural. And check all the filenames. Usually filename is snake_case of ClassName

Comment: Thanks. I have change the require/requyire_relatives but I'm going to have to research the order of the classes to get this right I think. I have customers who will go to see a film and then have tickets is the join table. I've had a go at swapping them around but still have the error.